# How to distort perspective with php imagick at a set angle

Tags: php, imagick, angle, distortion

I have an image that I'm trying to distort at a 30 degree angle.

So far I'm working off some arbitrary control points from an example.

My code thus far:

```
$im = new imagick($thefile);

      $points = array( 10, 10, 10, 5,

                    10, $im->getImageHeight() - 20,
                    10, $im->getImageHeight() - 5,

                    $im->getImageWidth() - 10, 10,
                    $im->getImageWidth() - 10, 20,

                    $im->getImageWidth() - 10, $im->getImageHeight() - 10,
                    $im->getImageWidth() - 10, $im->getImageHeight() - 30);
      $im->setImageMatte(true);
      $im->setImageVirtualPixelMethod( imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_TRANSPARENT );
      $im->distortImage( Imagick::DISTORTION_PERSPECTIVE, $points, TRUE );
      $im->writeImage($thefile);
```

Also I don't want to lose any of the image, so I'll need to figure out what size the new image should be to not lose any of it.

[distort http://sadtoe.com/temp/distort.jpg](http://sadtoe.com/temp/distort.jpg)

Thanks for any insight

Edit: After looking at how I created the example image in photoshop, I noticed that the rotation was set to 30, as was the horizontal skew. So maybe perspective distortion isn't the easiest way to do this, if I can find a way to rotate and skew.